# Flutter put parameter to rest api

Tags: flutter, dart

My API expect two parameter email and password. How put par_email and par_pass to my URL now I'm put fixed value.

Eg.

```
signIn(String par_email, par_pass) async {
  var jsonResponse = null;
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https('MYURL', 'Login/user@user.com/12345'));
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {
      print('OK');
    }
  }
  else {
    print('Error');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide dynamic values to a string use `$` sign before the variable.

```dart
signIn(String par_email, par_pass) async {
  var jsonResponse = null;
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https('MYURL', 'Login/$par_email/$par_pass'));
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {
      print('OK');
    }
  }
  else {
    print('Error');
  }
}
```

If you require a member of a class then use

```dart
Text("this is a ${dummy.name}");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass your variables as query parameters then follow my answer and to pass it in your url path refer [Ashutosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68302651/7349428)

The third parameter of `Uri.https()` method accepts query parameters as a Map object

Example from your code:

```
signIn(String par_email,String par_pass) async {
  final queryParameters = {                 // <--- Map of your paramters
  'email': par_email,
  'pwd': par_pass
  };
  var jsonResponse = null;
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https('MYURL', 'Login/',queryParameters));           // <--- Add here   
  if(response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if(jsonResponse != null) {
      print('OK');
    }
  }
  else {
    print('Error');
  }
}
```

Comment: i guess you misunderstood the problem. He wants to have those two variables in param.    `Login/user@user.com/12345` is hardcoded value

Comment: Ohh! I understand it now that I've read it again. Thanks for pointing it out! I've edited my answer :)